# node calling a subfunction from global

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have searched all over the internet without results (probably because i don't know the right search terms). I am currently writing a script with node for my raspberry pi in which i control a lcd with a [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lcdi2c). But because i can't run this plugin on my pc i wanted to mock it. i tried

```
var lcd = function(){
lcd.prototype.on = function(){
    lcdStatus = 1;
    console.log("The screen is on");
}
lcd.prototype.off = function(){
    lcdStatus = 0;
    console.log("The screen is of");
}
this.println = function(content, line){
    contentLcd[line] = content;
    console.log("------------------");
    console.log("|", contentLcd[1], "|");
    console.log("|", contentLcd[2], "|");
    console.log("------------------");       
}

this.clear = function(){
    contentLcd = [];
}
}
```

and then call the mock library the same way as i do with the regular one.

```
lcd.on():
lcd.println("Hello world!", 1);
```

on which i receive the error

```
lcd.println is not a function
```

i have been strugglin with this for a solid 3 hours.

Comment: Can you please provide what files each of these snippets are in?

Comment: For testing purposes i worked in one file only (meaning the function and the call to it were in the same file). Later my idea was to import the mock library instead of the official one when on pc.

Comment: I cleaned up your code and added my answer below. Be sure to give it a look.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things first you are not returning the object from the function, **I have added return this at the end of the function**. Then create an object and call the on method it works. Execute the below code

```
var lcd = function(){
lcd.prototype.on = function(){
    lcdStatus = 1;
    console.log("The screen is on");
}
lcd.prototype.off = function(){
    lcdStatus = 0;
    console.log("The screen is of");
}
this.println = function(content, line){
    contentLcd[line] = content;
    console.log("------------------");
    console.log("|", contentLcd[1], "|");
    console.log("|", contentLcd[2], "|");
    console.log("------------------");       
}

this.clear = function(){
    contentLcd = [];
}

return this;
}

var lcd1 = new lcd()

lcd1.on()
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, here is a cleaner way to do what you are looking for:

```
var lcd = function() {
    var that = this;
    that.lcdStatus;
    that.contentLcd = [];

    that.on = function(){
        that.lcdStatus = 1;
        console.log("The screen is on");
    }
    that.off = function(){
        that.lcdStatus = 0;
        console.log("The screen is of");
    }
    that.println = function(content, line){
        that.contentLcd[line] = content;
        console.log("------------------");
        console.log("| " + that.contentLcd[line] + " |");
        console.log("------------------");       
    }

    that.clear = function(){
        that.contentLcd = [];
    }
};

var LCD = new lcd();

LCD.on();
LCD.println("Hello world!", 1);
```

As you can see, I formatted your code and added the keyword `that` to hold the place of the methods "this".

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks!, but a question still remains. Why did you assign this tot that. Was is to order the code or does it have any other meaning?

Comment: @jollerWhite I apologize, I am just seeing this now. I do it this way because its easier for me to discern which scope I'm using when I'm in an objects object function and so on. Makes it easier than having to rely on `this` for every scope